# Shift Column Values based on Index PYSKPARK

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I HAVE:

| INDEX | A_0 | B_0 | A_1 | B_1 | A_2 | B_2 | A_3 | B_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00a | 00b | 01a | 01b | 02a | 02b | 03a | 03b |
| 1 |  |  | 11a | 11b | 12a | 12b | 13a | 13b |
| 2 |  |  |  |  | 21a | 22b | 23a | 23b |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 33a | 33a |

I SHOULD GET THIS WITHOUT USING UDF:

| INDEX | A_0 | B_0 | A_1 | B_1 | A_2 | B_2 | A_3 | B_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00a | 00b | 01a | 01b | 02a | 02b | 03a | 03b |
| 1 | 11a | 11b | 12a | 12b | 13a | 13b |  |  |
| 2 | 21a | 22b | 23a | 23b |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 33a | 33b |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: in the title, you say "based on index". Is there a connection between the index and the values on each line ?

Comment: the index just indicates the number of steps to the left

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

data = [ 
  (0,'00a','00b','01a','01b','02a','02b','03a','03b')
, (1,None,None,'11a','11b','12a','12b','13a','13b')
, (2,None,None,None,None,'21a','22b','23a','23b')
, (3,None,None,None,None,None,None,'33a','33a')
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['INDEX','A_0','B_0','A_1','B_1','A_2','B_2','A_3','B_3'])    

df = df.withColumn('to_array', psf.array_except(psf.array('A_0','B_0','A_1','B_1','A_2','B_2','A_3','B_3'), psf.array(psf.lit(None))))

df.select(
    psf.col('index')
,   psf.col('to_array')[0].alias('A_0')
,   psf.col('to_array')[1].alias('B_0')
,   psf.col('to_array')[2].alias('A_1')
,   psf.col('to_array')[3].alias('B_1')
,   psf.col('to_array')[4].alias('A_2')
,   psf.col('to_array')[5].alias('B_2')
,   psf.col('to_array')[6].alias('A_3')
,   psf.col('to_array')[7].alias('B_3')
).show()
```

Convert cols into an array, drop NULLs to 'shift-left', extract back to cols